# Can't create instance of class from other file in Atom/Hydrogen

Tags: python, atom-editor, hydrogen

I am having problems with Hydrogen in Atom on MacOS when trying to create an instance of a class from another file/module. The code *does* work when run in the command-line, but not in Atom. I have already set the directory to start kernel in to "Current directory of the file", which enables me to create an object of that other file and use functions, but not classes.

Here is the code in the two respective files. Again, importing File2 is not the problem, neither is using functions from File2 in File1. It is only classes that don't work.

```
#File1
    import File2
    from File2 import MyClass
    y=MyClass('test')
    print(y.name)

#File2
    class MyClass:
        def __init__(self, x):
            self.name=x
```

Running File1 gives me the error message, when run in Atom.

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-92-444367378d7c> in <module>
----> 1 from File2 import MyClass

ImportError: cannot import name 'MyClass' from 'File2'     (/Users/.../File2.py)
```

Comment: If I do this i get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.File2'; '__main__' is not a package`